# Access Heading of Google Street View Path Arrows

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am creating an app that allows you to programmatically advance through google street view. My question is how do I access the heading value of the arrows overlayed on the map? I want to set the heading in each panorama that I advance to to be the same as that of the overlaid arrows. Thank you!

[image]

Here's the code that I am doing to advance to the next panorama. I first determine what is the next closest panorama and then I advance to it:

```
function findNextPanorama() {

    if (panorama != null) {
        currentLatLng = panorama.getPosition();
        var myPano = panorama.getPov().heading;
        var myPanoVal = panorama.getPov();
        if (myPano < 0) {
            myPano = myPano + 360;
        }
        var links = panorama.getLinks();
        var i = 0;
        var headingArrays = [];
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            headingArrays.push(links[i].heading);
        }

        var closestHeading = closest(myPano, headingArrays);

        //Set pano to the next closest pano
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            if (links[i].heading == closestHeading) {
                panorama.setPano(links[i].pano);
                i = links.length;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you have the answer? I'm interested in the same issue. please tag me if you have it. or post your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewLink) contains a heading.

Although you might need to keep track of the last location to determine which way you are going.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may've asked the question wrong. I know that the link contains a heading but is that the same heading as the overlaid arrows? For example, if you are going north and you go to the intersection of an East-West street and click the right arrow to go East the panorama will change but you will still be facing north and not facing east like the arrows are. I want to change the heading so that you are always looking in the same direction that the arrows are facing.

Comment: What problem are you having doing that? You need to set the [POV](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPov) of the [panorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama). Don't see any code in your question, so can't tell what you are and aren't doing.

Comment: Ok, I've added my code to the question. This is the function being called that determines the next closest panorama and advances to it. I'm calling setPano to advance to the next panorama...I was assuming that it would also set the POV to that of the next panorama but maybe I am incorrect. I previously was storing the last POV and calling setPov after I called setPano to set the Pov to that of the last panorama but that didnt work either